# Delete Task in Project Server PSI

Tags: c#, web-services, project-server, ms-project-server-2013, psi

I have a problem when i want to delete a task or tasks in project server i used this syntax, deleteTask is Guid[]

```
projectClient.QueueDeleteFromProject(jobUID, new Guid(sessionUID), new Guid(projectUID), deleteTask);
```

and wait for queue

```
 if (Helpers.WaitForQueue(SvcQueueSystem.QueueMsgType.ProjectUpdate,
                queueSystemClient, startTime))
            {
                deleted= true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The project was not updated: {0}.\n\tThe queue wait time exceeded 60 seconds.", projectUID);
            }
```

i just got unexpected result, that Task is not deleted, and i got problem when i want to check in the project. What queueMsgType that relevant to delete task in this problem ?

Comment: The code isn't clear as to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for queue `JobState` instead of `QueueMsgType`.Please see an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg221639.aspx) from MS article